# time in milliseconds in c99?

Tags: c, time, c99, time.h

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the milliseconds between some socket programming connections in C99 but getting 0 ms on the C99 and returns an actual value on the mac terminal. I included time parts of my code.

Init:

```
  struct timeval start,end;
  double t1,t2;
  t1 = 0.0;
  t2 = 0.0;
```

start of operation:

```
t1+=start.tv_sec+(start.tv_usec/1000000.0);
```

End of operation:

```
t2+=end.tv_sec+(end.tv_usec/1000000.0);
```

And then just printing the actual time in ms:

```
printf("Sent........RTT = %g ms\n",(t2-t1)/100);
```

Comment: I would worry about potentially large tv_sec values causing huge loss of precision of the msec values. I would subtract the two second values first. Or use very large integers to hold everything in msecs.

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit? i don't fully understand you

Comment: What do you mean by "the c99"? Linux? Windows? Something else?

Comment: C99 is the compiler with 1999 edition of C. I don't think it really matters on which system it exists on if you have it enabled. Please correct me if i'm wrong. @rici

Comment: The function you use to get the time is Posix, not part of any C standard, and its implementation (and precision) are dependent on the OS, not the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you update the `timeval` structures correctly, you are not calculating milliseconds, but rather whole seconds and you print the difference divided by 100 instead of multiplied by 1000. You would loose less precision by computing the time differences:

```
diff += (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000.0 + end.tv_usec / 1000.0 - start.tv_usec / 1000.0;

...

printf("Sent........RTT = %g ms\n", diff / 100);
```